# wicket download csv "Page expired" error

Tags: wicket

I am trying to download a csv file on click of a button. I have the following implementation, but the moment I click the button, I get a page expired message

```
WebResource export = new WebResource() {

        @Override
        public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

            for(Person person: tmpList){
                result.append(person.toCSV()).append("\n");
            }
            return new StringResourceStream(result, "text/plain");
        }

        @Override
        protected void setHeaders(WebResponse response) {
            super.setHeaders(response);
            response.setAttachmentHeader("person.csv");
        }
    };
    export.setCacheable(false);
    form.add(new ResourceLink("exportLink", export));
```

my html markup is as follows

```
<a wicket:id="exportLink"><button class="button">Export</button></a>
```

Comment: It works for me, so the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: If i change the URL from http://localhost:8010/myapp/wicket/?wicket:interface=:4:loggingForm:exportLink:3:IResourceListener:: to http://localhost:8010/myapp/wicket?wicket:interface=:4:loggingForm:exportLink:3:IResourceListener::      I removed the / after wicket/?...it works fine.

Comment: @user, if you've found your final answer, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: well that is not an answer, it was just somethign i found out, but all the link URL are generated by wicket so I don't know if I can control if wicket should put a / or not. I am still looking for an answer

Comment: Can you post the part of your web.xml where you map your wicket filter to a url?

Comment: I want to create a WebResource item, but it doesn't let me. It said: WebResource cannot resolved to a type why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of serialization. one of the classes were not serialized

Comment: How to achieve the same in the wicket 9.x version?
Because whatever used in this example has been removed.